# Updating SQL Server based on unique row using WHILE LOOP

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update my table using WHILE LOOP, unfortunately, instead of updating it based on **employeeidno**, it gathers all the total **aremployee** in all **employeeidno** and then update the row of all **employeeidno** based on it.

Is there a way to segregate the `SET @aremployee` based on **employeeidno**?

What I basically what for this query is that for every WHILE LOOP it will capture the data gathered, and then add it to the next loop, but is based on **employeeidno**.

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @aremployee FLOAT = 0;
WHILE @cnt <= (SELECT TOP 1 RIGHT(accountcode,2) FROM accounting_tblearningsamendmentaccount_db WHERE LEFT(accountcode,2) = '02' AND approvedby IS NOT NULL ORDER BY accountcode DESC)
BEGIN
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    UPDATE accounting_tblpayroll_db
    SET @aremployee = @aremployee + x.aremployee,
        accounting_tblpayroll_db.aremployee = @aremployee
    FROM (SELECT 
        MAX(RTRIM(LTRIM(employeeidno))) AS 'employeeidno', 
        SUM(debit) AS 'aremployee', 
        MAX(accountcode) as 'accountcode',
        MAX(RTRIM(LTRIM(referenceno))) AS 'referenceno', 
        MAX(RTRIM(LTRIM(particulars))) AS 'particulars', 
        MAX(RTRIM(LTRIM(postedby))) AS 'postedby', 
        MAX(RTRIM(LTRIM(approvedby))) AS 'approvedby', 
        MAX(RTRIM(LTRIM(notedby))) AS 'notedby' 
        FROM accounting_tblearningsamendment_db WHERE LEFT(accountcode,2) = LEFT('02000',2) 
        AND accountcode != '02001' AND accountcode != '02002'
        AND payrolldue is null AND datedue BETWEEN '2020-10-06' AND '2020-10-20'
        AND accountcode = CONCAT('020', CONCAT(CASE WHEN @cnt < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END , @cnt))
        GROUP BY employeeidno) AS x
    WHERE x.employeeidno = accounting_tblpayroll_db.employeeidno
        AND x.aremployee < 
        (((accounting_tblpayroll_db.cutoffpay + accounting_tblpayroll_db.leave + accounting_tblpayroll_db.nightdifferential + accounting_tblpayroll_db.regularholiday + accounting_tblpayroll_db.specialholiday + accounting_tblpayroll_db.additionalincome + accounting_tblpayroll_db.overtime
        
        + accounting_tblpayroll_db.apemployee + accounting_tblpayroll_db.thmonth + accounting_tblpayroll_db.christmasbonus + accounting_tblpayroll_db.administrativeallowance + accounting_tblpayroll_db.supervisoryallowance
     + accounting_tblpayroll_db.hazardallowance + accounting_tblpayroll_db.shortageallowance + accounting_tblpayroll_db.licenseallowance + accounting_tblpayroll_db.transportationallowance + loyaltyincentiveallowance - '1000.00'
        )
        - (accounting_tblpayroll_db.sss_ee + accounting_tblpayroll_db.med_ee + accounting_tblpayroll_db.pagibig_ee + accounting_tblpayroll_db.late + accounting_tblpayroll_db.undertime)))
        AND accounting_tblpayroll_db.datefrom = '2020-10-06' 
        AND accounting_tblpayroll_db.dateto = '2020-10-20';
    END;
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

This is the simplified version:

```
DROP TABLE #temtable1;
DROP TABLE #temtable2;

CREATE TABLE #temtable1
(
    referenceno int,
    employeeid varchar(10),
    ccode varchar(10),
    amount float(10)
);

INSERT INTO #temtable1
(referenceno,employeeid,ccode,amount)
VALUES('1001','2001','3001','11000.00');
INSERT INTO #temtable1
(referenceno,employeeid,ccode,amount)
VALUES('1003','2002','3002','11000.00');
INSERT INTO #temtable1
(referenceno,employeeid,ccode,amount)
VALUES('1005','2003','3003','11000.00');

INSERT INTO #temtable1
(referenceno,employeeid,ccode,amount)
VALUES('1001','2001','3004','10000.00');
INSERT INTO #temtable1
(referenceno,employeeid,ccode,amount)
VALUES('1003','2002','3005','10000.00');
INSERT INTO #temtable1
(referenceno,employeeid,ccode,amount)
VALUES('1005','2003','3006','10000.00');
CREATE TABLE #temtable2
(
    referenceno int,
    employeeid varchar(10),
    total float(10)
);

INSERT INTO #temtable2
(referenceno,employeeid,total)
VALUES('1001','2001',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temtable2
(referenceno,employeeid,total)
VALUES('1002','2002',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temtable2
(referenceno,employeeid,total)
VALUES('1003','2003',NULL);


DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @total INT = 0;
WHILE @cnt <= 10
BEGIN
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;

UPDATE #temtable2
SET @total =  @total + x1.amount,
    total = @total
    FROM(SELECT
         MAX(referenceno) as referenceno, 
         MAX(employeeid) as employeeid, 
         ccode as ccode, 
         SUM(amount) as amount
         FROM #temtable1
         WHERE
         ccode = CONCAT('30', CONCAT(CASE WHEN @cnt < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END , @cnt))
         GROUP BY
         employeeid,ccode) AS x1
 WHERE x1.employeeid = #temtable2.employeeid
        AND x1.amount < 25000
 END
 
 select * from #temtable2
```

Current Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

What I intend for this is that the query will loop and add all **code** that starts with 3, depending on what employeeid the data is under.

The query will the first loop starting 3001, then up to 3010, and add it consecutively until it will not exceed 25000, but it's on every employeeid.

Comment: Could you please provide some consumable sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Why do you want to use a ``WHILE` loop in the first place? SQL is a set based language, you should be aiming for set based solutions.

Comment: @Larnu exactly. That's why I asked for samples and desired output. My first guess would be to change this to a solution based on window function and unbounded preceding... but hard to tell without real examples I guess.

Comment: @Tyron78 . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  Sample code is good, but not a replacement for a clear explanation for humans.

Comment: @Tyron78 I added new details, apologies, I forgot to add my test data.

Comment: @Larnu I added the sample data. I hope this helps.